# Overwriting Documents in DocumentDB

Tags: json, azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-cosmosdb

I have a eventhub/stream analytics/documentdb chain, stream analytics job takes json object and persist it in a documentdb collection by id.

If a document with the same id exists in the collection, it should get overwritten right? But this is not happening.

let say I have this object in the collection:

```
 {
  "id" : "001",
  "array":[
     {
      "key1" : "value1"
    },
     {
      "key2" : "value2" 
    },
     {
      "key3" : "value3" 
    {
     ]
}
```

And the new document that is persisted by the stream job is :

```
{
  "id" : "001",
  "array":[
      {
       "key4" : "value4"
     },
      {
       "key5" : "value5" 
     }
      ]
 }
```

The new document that I get in the collection looks like this:

```
 {
  "id" : "001",
  "array":[
     {
      "key4" : "value4"
    },
     {
      "key5" : "value5" 
    },
     {
      "key3" : "value3" 
    {
     ]
}
```

The array doesn't get overwritten, only object within the size of the new document that is being saved. If oldarray.size > newarray.size some old data will still be there.

I want to prevent this. I want to overwrite all the document and get rid of all the old data.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please share your code for saving the document.

Comment: @GauravMantri In stream analytics I have Json as input and Json as output and I modify the structure using the query. Like this question I asked a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557900/wrapping-json-into-output-stream-analytics-query